# Is it safe to mutate prevState passed to setState in react?

Tags: reactjs

For example, this is an onChange callback of some input in some epic complicated form.

```
  someFormInputOnChange(e){
    this.setState((prevState, props)=>{
      prevState.form.someList[e.target.someIndex].someItem[e.target.someField] = e.target.value
      return prevState
    })
  }
```

Is it ok to mutate the prevState passed to it and then return this prevState? If not, why?

Comment: This would create unwanted complication as state changes will sometime use shallow comparsion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result returned in `setState` is being used by React to check if prevState is same as the result

if you do mutation, React will think they are the same object, and will not rerender your Component

Comment: It make sense in PureComponent. Is prevStage mutation ok in Component?

Comment: @lotsofone you are right, never know Component is ok

https://codesandbox.io/embed/setstate-issue-yj995?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

but I think is best not to do that, because this is anti pattern and if you check https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
(state, props) => stateChange
state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props.
```